# When published my ionic app to playstore, its not visible on lot of devices. But its previous version was

Tags: android, ionic-framework, device

I published my app on playstore with a new version. Its previous version was available on almost every device. Like i have two Samsung models one is Note 10 lite and other is A21, App's previous version was available on both the phones. On both the phones i am not able to view the app on play store. And when i try to open it via playstore link available on my website. Its showing "Device isn't compatible with this app.". I have checked MinSDK version also. This is not causing any problem. Also checked other solutions given by users on google. Like  line is not available in my AndroidManifest.xml.
For more information i am pasting my AndroidManifest.xml here.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="311175" android:versionName="3.2.2" package="com.ionicframework.cs0786764578" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.ionicframework.cs0786764578" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.ionicframework.cs0786764578.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ionicframework.cs0786764578.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Information regarding my config.xml file is mentioned below regarding versions:

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I have changed the targetSDKVersion to 30. Actually all the devices that i have mentioned in question are running on Android 10. And app was intended to run on API level 29 i.e. below Android 10.
When the targetSDKVersion was 29 App was supported by 11k approx devices. When i changed it to 30, supported device list is 14K.